# Как поменять тему в Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, sublime-text

Как поменять тему в Sublime Text 3 ? А то уже глаза кровью наливаются от розового текста HTML-документа :(

Answer (score 1):

В меню Sublime: Preferences - Color Scheme

Сами можно добавлять пакетами, стандартные темы находятся в пакете %Program_ files%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package

Answer (score 0):

`preferences` -> `themes` -> `*выбираете тему*`

для цветовой схемы - вместо `themes` - `color scheme`.

советую **solarized**

Answer (score 0):

Если вас смущают ярко-розовые HTML-тэги в цветовой схеме Монокаи, то, как сказал FODD, идите в Preferences -> Color Scheme, там по умолчанию будет выпадать список из пяти предустановленных цветовых схем. Их и выбираете.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в %Program_ files%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package лучше не лезть.